# DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt") shows up reversed in windows 7

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-7

Okay, I have a Label on my program that gets updated with the time on a timer like so:

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

It should print out (and does when hovering over the variable in Visual Studio):

```
12/15/2010 8:41 PM
```

But instead prints out:

```
PM 8:41 12/15/2010
```

This is the only place in my code that the label is getting changed.  It works in windows XP but now I'm using my code in windows 7, it gets jacked up.  Please help me.  I'm unsure as to why this is going on.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what happens if you remove the CultureInfo?

Comment: What is the RightToLeft setting of the control?

Comment: What language is this?  C#?  It might help to tag it as such so it gets on the radar of that community...

Comment: @RedDeckWins: Please post as an answer

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `RightToLeft` setting of the control is `true` - change that to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Argh, `RightToLeft` setting was true.  Don't know why but it was. Thanks @RedDeckWins!